# Error: android.view.inflateExeption in CustomTextView

Tags: android, exception, casting, textview, android-inflate

I have a menu activity that gets user setting of font and size and line spacing of text in all of TextView's, so i need a CustomTextView class to set these changes but my custom TextView does't work and give inflate Exception in logcat window. tank's a lot for your helps!

my CustomTextView:

```
package com.niloo.test2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

Context context;
SharedPreferences shp = context.getSharedPreferences("text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int size = shp.getInt("size", 22);
int fasle = shp.getInt("fasle", 1);
String font = shp.getString("font", "bmitra");


public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    if (!isInEditMode())
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/"+font));
        setTextSize(size);
        setLineSpacing(fasle, 1);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (! isInEditMode())
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/"+font));
        setTextSize(size);
        setLineSpacing(fasle, 1);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (!isInEditMode())
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/"+font));
        setTextSize(size);
        setLineSpacing(fasle, 1);
}

protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

my XML code:

```
      <com.niloo.test2.CustomTextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_onv_amoozsh"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.5"
           android:textColor="@color/sabz_lajani"
           android:textSize="25sp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.niloo.test2.CustomTextView
          android:id="@+id/tv_num_amoozsh"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
          android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
          android:layout_weight="0.75"
          android:textColor="@color/sabz_lajani"
          android:textSize="35sp" />
```

and my main class:

```
final CustomTextView tv_onv_amoozsh= (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_onv_amoozsh);
        tv_onv_amoozsh.setText("page");
final CustomTextView tv_num_amoozsh=(CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_num_amoozsh);
        tv_num_amoozsh.setText(sfhe_num);
```

LogCat Error:

```
02-03 22:41:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(19952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 22:41:38.329: E/AndroidRuntime(19952): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.niloo.test2/com.niloo.test2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #143: Error inflating class com.niloo.test2.CustomTextView
```

Comment: there will be some more details to that error from Logcat. Please add.

Comment: 02-04 22:33:28.770: E/AndroidRuntime(19045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 22:33:28.770: E/AndroidRuntime(19045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.niloo.test2/com.niloo.test2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #152: Error inflating class com.niloo.test2.CustomTextView
02-04 22:33:28.770: E/AndroidRuntime(19045):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
02-04 22:33:28.770: E/AndroidRuntime(19045):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this at the first view in your layout?

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Please post the full layout file (reduce it in your project to the minimum that is still failing. Maybe only have one view in it - your custom text )

EDIT:
The xml code you posted is invalid. Here is the fixed version that should work (do not omit "http://", remove semicolons)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sabzabi_kmrng"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.niloo.test2.MainActivity">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sabzabi_kmrng"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.niloo.test2.MainActivity" >
this is the first view!

Comment: Dear Dennis, tank's but there was all of "http://" in my code and think in my comment, automatically removed...!

Comment: so i tried again your updated XML code and anything changed, thus i think that the problem can't be from XML side! maybe I should,t define size of text in custom textView class with the font??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you're initializing `shp`, `size`, `fasle`, and `font` outside of the constructor.  These initializations happen before any constructor code is run.  `context` is never set and is null when `getSharedPreferences` is called on it.

Try this:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    private SharedPreferences shp;
    private int size;
    private int fasle;
    private String font;

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }
        shp = context.getSharedPreferences("text", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        size = shp.getInt("size", 22);
        fasle = shp.getInt("fasle", 1);
        font = shp.getString("font", "bmitra");
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/" + font));
        setTextSize(size);
        setLineSpacing(fasle, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it didn't work with same logcat error. so please guide me an alternative way!

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from this line:

```
setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/"+font));
```

Here we don't need to mention the keyword *"fonts/"* for path, because *getAssets()* method giving the route path of assets folder. So you can directly give font name like below:

```
setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font));
```